# bootstrap resize

Tags: css3, bootstrap, background, responsive

Как сделать, чтобы background-image и текст ресайзился в зависимости от ширины экрана, с сохранением пропорций. В частности пытаюсь сверстать на Bootstrap'e. 
ЗЫ. Высоту текста указываю в Em. Ниже код:

```
.main__text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: canter;
    color: #f1ede1;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 6em;
}
body {
    background-image: url(images/background.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Comment: С текстом проблему решил, указав высоту в vw.

Answer (score 0):

Что у вас не так с background? Все работает, см. пример.

```css
.main__text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: canter;
    color: #f1ede1;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 10vw;
}
body {
    background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8NJPgd7AQYU/maxresdefault.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main__text">Main text</div>
```